# How can I use RichEdit20W Control in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, c, winapi, richeditbox

Can someone help me with how to use RichEdit20W control in C# desktop application? I have a sample of how to use it in VC++ but I do not know how to implement in C#.

Answer (score 1):

You create an empty WindowsForms project, open the Toolbox and type 'Rich' into its search box. It will find 'RichTextBox'. You double-click it, to put it onto the form. Then you set its properties, as appropriate.
When you run the application, and then use SpyXX on it, you will see, that the control is using the class 'WindowsForms10.RichEdit20W.app.0.141b42a_r13_ad1', which is a wrapper for the class you wanted.